# How to hide AJAX calls/urls from the browser page source code?

Tags: javascript, php, security

I haven't find a right answer for this and decided to post it... I just finished a website that took me a while to get it done. This site is too interactive so it has quite a few ajax calls everywhere and the urls are visible (obviously), my website is done with php, vanilla js, jquery and mysql.

I can't deploy this website until I find a way to hide or at least prevent people from accessing one of those urls from the address bar. I don't know if the "robots.txt" might help here.

I've seen tons of sites that if I enter the "view source code" I can't see any url from that particular site. I can't also see any file extension such as .php or .py or whatver.. I can just see some .js files from external links such as the jquery CDN.

I hope I could get some help here since I'm excited to deploy this website. Thanks!

Comment: if the browser can run the code, the user can read the code. `prevent people from accessing one of those urls from the address bar` - make it a POST request. address bar urls use GET request

Comment: Obfuscating it in the code won't stop a smart attacker from using the network tab to find the requests. Nothing you send to the browser can be fully protected. Period.

Comment: Consider to secure your urls on server side. What is a point to hide them ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers... @RafaelHovsepyan Is a personal desire. So how do other website hide that content? One of those that I looked for is gamespot.com ... You can't see either server side extensions (.php por example) or any other url regarding the site itself... I was thinking on playing with sessions on the ajax url requests to prevent people from accessing them on the address bar.

Comment: FYI, a URL doesn't have to explicitly have ".php" in it to go to a PHP file.  A lot of modern frameworks use routing so that you have a URL such as example.com/controller/action/param1/value1.  Using Zend as an example, such a request would hit index.php and then call the actionAction() function in the application/controllers/ControllerController.php file.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thank you very much! Yes I know frameworks have tons of stuff I'm not familiarized with since I usually code vanilla. Thank you, I actually came to some conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an ajax router file php. js send to ajax router and router call function from true url